# How can I produce a scatterplot using ggplot in R where each column is a different colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of model-output in R that I want to plot using ggplot. I want to produce a scatter plot within which every column of data is a different colour. In the example here, I have three model outputs which I want to plot against 'measured'. What I want in the end is a scatter with three different 'clouds' of points, each of which is a different colour. Here is a reproducible example of what I have so far:

```
library(ggplot)
library(tidyverse)
#data for three different models as well as a column for 'observations' (measured)
output <- list(model1 = 1:10, model2 = 22:31, model3=74:83)
#create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  predicted = output,
  measured = 1:length(output[[1]]),
  #year = as.factor(data$year),
  #site = data$site
  #model = as.factor(names(output)),
  #stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
 fix.empty.names = TRUE)
#fix the column names
colnames(df)<-names(output)

#plot the data with a different colour for each column of data
p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      measured,
      predicted,
      colour =colnames(df)
    )
  ) +
  ylim(-5, 90)+
  theme_minimal() 
p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
print(p)
```

I am getting the error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'measured' not found`
why is 'measured' not being found? I can see it in the df?

Perhaps I needs to collapse all the model outputs into one column a create a column as a 'factor' column to 'assign' each data point to a particular model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that your `output` list only has as many elements as you have models, so it has no name for the last "measured" column and that gets overwritten with NA.
Compare:

```
colnames(df)<-names(output).                # NA in last col
colnames(df)<-c(names(output), "measured"). # fixed
```

Then, to plot your data in ggplot2 it's almost always better to convert to longer, "tidy" format, with one row per observation. `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` is great for that.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-measured,   # don't pivot "measured" -- keep in every row
               names_to = "model",   
               values_to = "predicted") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      measured,
      predicted,
      colour = model
    )
  ) +
  ylim(-5, 90)+
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. I understand that I need to explicitly add in the name of the 'measured' variable when creating dataframes this way. I'm not sure exactly how the `-measured` is referring back to the df here, but I don't know much about pipes, so maybe the hyphen has to do with that. I'll look it up now. Thanks again!

Comment: The "-measured" is one way to specify to `pivot_longer` that we want to pivot everything except that column. Could alternatively have used `pivot_longer(model1:model3, ...` for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the name of your object :

```
colnames(df)<-names(output)
```

So now your columns were not found.

I reorganized your object into a data frame that can be easily understood by ggplot2. Do not hesitate to look at your objects.

Here is one option :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#data for three different models as well as a column for 'observations' (measured)
output <- list(model1 = 1:10, model2 = 22:31, model3=74:83)

#create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  predicted = unlist(output),
  measured = 1:length(unlist(output)),
  model = names(output)
  )

#plot the data with a different colour for each column of data
p <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(measured, predicted,colour = model)) +
  ylim(-5, 90)+
  theme_minimal() 

p + geom_hline(yintercept=0)

print(p)
```

[plotwithgroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBKsV.png)

If you add this line :
facet_grid(~model) +

You can get this which sounds like what you were asking :
[plotwithfacet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwhr4.png)

Comment: Thanks, that is close, but not quite. You'll notice that the values for 'model1' are:1:10. In your example, the values for model1 are scattered across the values for the other models as well?